# Web Service Client Deployment

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service client (JAX-WS) and the stubs have been created using the wsimport tool.

Now once the client is packaged as an application, the location of the service (and only the location )changes.

Do I have to re run the whole ws-import tool once again to create new stubs for the new location. 
Is it possible to move the WSDL location to a Config so that the application do not have to be built again! I am working with net beans 6.5.

I suppose DII is an option, but is there a solution to make the code independent of the WSDL location.

Answer (score 1):

You may package the WSDL locally in your application (which is also reasonable for performance, since you're saving requests to the external file on runtime), see [developing client application with locally packaged WSDL](https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/Developing_client_application_with_locally_packaged_WSDL.html#Using__wsdlLocation_switch)